# nova-scheduler don`t rpc.cast to nova-compute, no errors, but vm in 'scheduling' state

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, nova-scheduler

OpenStack Juno + OpenContrail. Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. 2 node setup: control+compute.

1. Everything worked well.
2. Delete and reinstall compute node.
3. Now when starting new vm its stuck in 'scheduling' state.
4. No errors in logs.
5. With debug I see how nova-scheduler doing filtering and now should
   pass rpc.cast to nova-compute.
6. nova-compute shows nothing in debug.

p.s. rabbit is ok, I see many control connections and 3 connections from compute node.

Answer (score 0):

If you exec nova list, are you see network interfaces of the new vm?

Comment: no network interfaces. as I traced it:  
1) I call nova boot  
2) See request in nova-api debug logs  
3) See nova-schedule processing request  
and then only: 'scheduling' state VMs

Comment: Ok, can you check neutron logs? I think neutron can't create ports for vm.

Comment: I can`t check it right now, but every documentation I seen: next steps are scheduler -> compute -> conductor and only after this neutron should take place. will post results tomorrow.